# Problem with gdb while trying to use with an executable

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I have an executable that was built in Qt. When I try to use the command, "gdb my_executable", I am able to set breakpoint only for the functions that are in the main.cpp file, For all other functions, I get the message,

No source file named filename.cpp
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n

I even tried giving the full path name but it doesn't work. Could you please help me out.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile all your sources with the -g option. This will include debugging information in your .o files, like information about what the source file name is and what line number corresponds to each instruction.

Comment: Also verify that you are using the debug versions of your Qt libraries (dll, shared or static).  The debug versions have symbol information in them, which helps when setting breakpoints.

Answer (score -1):

Compile with -gstabs option if using the gcc toolchain.

Comment: gstabs is automatically selected on the (very few) platforms that still use it, and is long obsolete on all others.